# The following code gives an error: 'Session' is a type, which is not valid in the given context. What is causing the error?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, authentication

I am not understanding the error and would like some help or guidance. I am trying to connect to my MySql server and do authentication in order for a user to log in. I have been stuck trying to figure out this issue but I am not having too much luck researching the error specific to Session.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FishStore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MySqlX.XDevAPI;

namespace FishStore.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Account/Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Autherize(FishStore.Models.User userModel)
    {
        using (LoginDataBaseEntities db = new LoginDataBaseEntities())
        {
            var userDetails = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == userModel.Username && x.Password == userModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Wrong username or password";
                return View("Login", userModel);
            }
            else 
            {
                Session["userId"] = userDetails.UserID;
                return RedirectToAction("Data", "AccountPage");
            }
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        return View();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correctly tag your question, it will help you get correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an MVC Core controller. `Session` is no longer  property of the `Controller` base class.

You need `HttpContext.Session`.

Sessions are very different in Core from Framework. See [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/12/01/working-with-session.aspx).

Comment: So would I replace it with HttpContext.Session["userId"] = userDetails.UserId; I tried to do that and it seems to not work.

Comment: No - Session in Core is very different. Follow the link I gave.

Comment: Thank you so much!